# Paytm app invoke always return onTransactionCancel

Tags: android, payment-gateway, paytm

I tried Paytm App Invoke on Android for payment in my app.
I successfully call Initiate Transaction API and get the TxnToken and pass this token via this code which is given in their documentation.

```
        Intent paytmIntent = new Intent();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putDouble("nativeSdkForMerchantAmount", Double.valueOf(amount));
        bundle.putString("orderid", orderId);
        bundle.putString("txnToken", txnToken);
        bundle.putString("mid", Constants.M_ID);

        paytmIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("net.one97.paytm", "net.one97.paytm.AJRJarvisSplash"));
        paytmIntent.putExtra("paymentmode", 2); // You must have to pass hard coded 2 here, Else your transaction would not proceed.
        paytmIntent.putExtra("bill", bundle);

        startActivityForResult(paytmIntent, activityRequestCode);
```

It opens the Paytm app but it always returns `onTransactionCancel` in `nativeSdkForMerchantMessage` key and empty in `response` key in `onActivityResult`

It is the response of my initiate transaction API:

```
{"head":{"responseTimestamp":"1573726921245","version":"v1","signature":"D66wa0T6BEfN1zh8eX0wPGnxir54fBuux0kQbxRxqLymufjWJxXV2mYVR12UWRmwCmneQKmH8DTqGYdOzKLADjABcDz3LJQSztyUTZA6X/I="},"body":{"resultInfo":{"resultStatus":"S","resultCode":"0000","resultMsg":"Success"},"txnToken":"38ebe038e2ef43e54c6da7fce91f73531573726984538","isPromoCodeValid":false,"authenticated":false}}
```

I am not getting any `errorCode` or error message in `response`. 
Please help me in figure out what am I doing wrong or

> how to get the error message/response in my `onActivityResult`.?

Comment: For small apps, I use [open-upi](https://github.com/theapache64/open-upi), as it supports more payment gateway such as PhonePe, PayTm , GooglePay etc. and all wth minimal configuration and zero cost

Comment: How did you solve it?